# jQuery Menu Hover On Everything But With Sub Menu

Tags: jquery, hover, submenu

I currently have my menu so that when I hover over one item all the other list items fade out. I run into a problem when I have a sub menu. I want the item I'm hovered on (the sub menu parent) to stay highlighted as I move my mouse through the sub menu. I do not want the effect to carry to the sub menu. How can I get this to work?

This is the js fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jfarr07/9bmjdryv/10/

jQuery

```
var timeout = 0;
$('#mainNav li a').hover(function() {
    $(this).stop(true, true).addClass('hovered').fadeTo(100,1);
    fadeOutArticles();
}, function() {
    $(this).removeClass('hovered');
    fadeOutArticles();
});
function fadeOutArticles(){
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    $('#mainNav li a').not('.hovered').fadeTo(100,0.6, function(){
        timeout = setTimeout(function(){
            if($('#mainNav li a.hovered').length==0){
                $('#mainNav li a').stop(true,true).fadeTo(100, 1);
            }
        }, 0);
    });     
}
```

Comment: This would be the right way to do it http://jsfiddle.net/L94N6/2/

Comment: see the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/9bmjdryv/12/  dirty edited code updated from your fiddle

Comment: @Akki619 This solution took away fading all other list items by hovering over one item.

Comment: @Akki619 your second solution is very glitchy in all browsers.

Comment: If you see the fiddle it will fade with one LOC change. I am OOO now, if you are not able to find, I will update tomorrow.

Comment: Try to make it not glitchy, thats why provided first link to help.